# Does 'getting ages' idiomatically sound natural?

Tags: idioms, expressions

We're usually taught (in Korea) to say *getting old* to describe that something/someone is aging, but I found out this can sound unnecessarily exaggerated as if it's running out of its lifespan. To tone down this expression I was thinking about saying *getting ages* instead of *getting old*, but I'm not sure it is idiomatically natural. I cannot easily find the usage of this, so I postulate maybe it's not that common and there must be a better expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, "getting ages" is completely wrong here. If you were asking a group of people to tell you their ages so you could write them down - for example, if you were conducting a survey - and someone asked you what you were doing, you might casually say:

> What are you doing?
>
> I'm getting ages.

This is totally different than what you're tying to say.

There is nothing wrong with "getting old." You can weaken it by saying "getting old**er**." If you are a child or young adult, you can say "I'm growing up" or "I'm maturing" (the latter has some additional connotations you may not want to evoke).